# jackson nested deserializer call inside another one

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I've a class like:

```
class A {
    private String z;
    private String y;
    private List<B> bs;
}

class B {
    private String x;
}
```

In order to serialize `A`, I've created two serializer, one for `A` and another one for `B`:

```
public class ASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {

@Override
public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField("z", value.getZ());
    gen.writeStringField("y", value.getY());

    gen.writeFieldName("bs");
    gen.writeStartArray(value.getBs().size());
    for (B b : value.getBs())
        gen.writeObject(b);
    gen.writeEndArray();

    gen.writeEndObject();  
}

public class ASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A>
{
@Override
public void serialize(B value, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField("x", value.getX());

    gen.writeEndObject();  
}
```

So, `BSerializer.serialize()` is automatically called when inside `ASerializer.serialize()` calls `gen.writeObject(b)`.

I'm trying to do the same for serializing A objects.
So, I have two serializers one for A and another one for B. The problem is I don't know how on earth I can set Jackson calls automatically to `BDeserializer` inside `ADeserializer`.

public class ADeserializer extends JsonDeserializer
{

```
@Override
public A deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    A a = null;

    JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

    String z = node.get("z").asText();
    String y = node.get("y").asText();
    List<B> bs = node.get("bs") //.asListofB
    //...
```

The question is, how can I call to deseriazer from another one?

**Note:**
`A` and `B` are third party classes. So I'm not able to annotate these.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can't annotate these classes directly, you can write "mixin" annotated classes. These are classes that only exist to hold annotations, which are then applied as if they were on some other class. For example:

```
public abstract class AMixin {
    @JsonProperty public abstract String getZ();
    @JsonProperty public abstract String getY();
    @JsonProperty public abstract List<B> getBs();
}
```

To configure the mixin:

```
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(A.class, AMixin.class);
```

If you go down the route of writing deserializers based on the `JsonNode` representation (btw extend `StdNodeBasedDeserializer`) then you encounter the problem that deserializers in general work on a stream, not a tree node. Now, any tree node can be traversed as a stream: and it's therefore possible to take `node.get("bs")`, call `traverse()` and thus get a `JsonParser` which you can pass to a deserializer. Of course, if that deserializer ends up converting the stream back into a tree node, it's a bit of a waste...

I did end up creating something to encapsulate this (and take a shortcut if the next deserializer was itself a `StdNodeBasedDeserializer` and avoid the traverse), but I don't have it to hand right now. IMHO producing mixin classes to get Jackson to build the serializer/deserializers (that stay in sync!) is a better approach.